# Is there any way to simplify this difference of factorials?

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

is there any way to simplify this expression or write it as a neat, concise formula?

$$ \frac{(2m)!}{2m!} - \frac{(x+y)!}{x!y!} \cdot \frac{ [2m-(x+y)]!}{ (m-x)!(m-y)!} $$

Thank you!

Comment: Is $2m!$ = 2 by m!?

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

The neatest possible I guess would be
$$
\frac{m!}{2} \cdot \binom{2m}{m} - \binom{x+y}{x} \cdot \binom{2m-(x+y)}{m-x}
$$